# Custom server error codes spring MVC & tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, spring-mvc, custom-error-handling

I'm writting a webapp that should be able to handle a request as following:
localhost:8080/WeddingApp/report?tid=1

I want that in case the server gets the following requests:
localhost:8080/WeddingApp/report
localhost:8080/WeddingApp/report?tid=

to issue error 404/500 rather than the default 400. Not only changing the page that error 400 redirect to, but to change the error code retrived from the server as well.

How can that be achieved?

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where your code looks for the request parameter `tid`, set the response status to your desired code like this:

```
response.setStatus(404);
```

Where `response` is the `HttpServletResponse` from your servlet class:

```
import java.io.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;

public class ServletExample extends HttpServlet {
  private void doGetOrPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // ~~~ your code snippet ~~~
    String value = request.getParameter("tid");
    if (value == null) {
        response.setStatus(404);
    } else {
        // do something
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm using multistream controller with @RequestMapping annotation. My code actually looks like the following:
@RequestMapping("report")
public String report(Model model, @RequestParam(required=false) Integer tid) {...}

Comment: The concept is the same - the HttpServletResponse object is still accessible in Spring - how you manipulate it is up to you.